# Parsing unsuccessfully JSON Objects with retrofit2

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 in my code with gson.
i can parse almost all needed, but when parsing a specific JSON, I have a problem.

This is the JSON:

```
{
"data": [
{
"id": "001",
"direccion": "Cascada 3",
"provincia": "Burgos"
},
{
"id": "002",
"direccion": "Lago 21",
"provincia": "Zamora"
}
]
}
```

**I know that what I am going to write has been commented a lot but, please, read until the end**

When parsing it shows this error:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

If I delete the name of the object “data” from JSON, then I can parse it perfectly, like this:

```
[
{
"id": "001",
"direccion": "Cascada 3",
"provincia": "Burgos"
},
{
"id": "002",
"direccion": "Lago 21",
"provincia": "Zamora"
}
]
```

**The JSON continues to open with an object, but it can be parsed perfectly.**
This leads me to think that I am not indicating in the code how to parse the object called "data", I think the problem is that.

Tiendas.java (I use @serializedName for a possible solution that I have read but it does not work)

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Tiendas {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("provincia")
    private String provincia;
    @SerializedName("direccion")
    private String direccion;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getProvincia() {
        return provincia;
    }
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }


}
```

The interface

```
 @GET("tiendas/tiends.json")
 Call<List<Tiendas>> getTiendas();
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void getGETsinParametros() {

     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl("https://www.MY_URL_BASE.com/")
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build();

     JsonPlaceHolderApi jspAPI = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

     Call<List<Tiendas>> call = jspAPI.getTiendas();

     call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Tiendas>>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<List<Tiendas>> call, Response<List<Tiendas>> response) {

             if (!response.isSuccessful()) {

                 Log.e(TAG, "Código de respuesta no exítoso:" + response.code());

             } else {

                 Log.d(TAG,"response code:"+response.code());

                 List<Tiendas> listaObtenida = response.body();

                 for(Tiendas stores: listaObtenida){
                     String content = "";
                     content += "id" + stores.getId() + "\n";
                     content += "provincia" + stores.getProvincia() + "\n";
                     content += "direccion" + stores.getDireccion() + "\n";

                  jsonText.append(content);

                 }
             }

         }

         @Override
         public void onFailure(Call<List<Tiendas>> call, Throwable t) {
             Log.e("TAG, "error:" + t.getMessage());
         }
     });

 }
```

Can someone tell me how to fix the error with "data", or with what is necessary to make it work?

**The JSONs are external, so I can't modify them.**

Thanks and regards.

Comment: How did you event delete the name of the object without messing up the Json? since you said you cannot change the api response from your end ?
And also, if you use the generate Gson tool, you should get the structure well,
Do you mind if I paste the generated GSON format I have ?

Comment: I did it by downloading the JSON, changing it, and uploading it to a personal server.
This answer is not helpful.

Comment: it's not an answer! it's a comment.
And also you did not show the JSON class you used to deserialize the actual response object which is where I think the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to be rude :)

Comment: I'm happy you got what you wanted ;) also it's common for some programmers to be rude...lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the wrapper for the Array object to get the list of tiendas:

```
public class Data{

    private List<Tiendas> data;

    public List<Tiendas> getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

And call it in your interface:

```
 @GET("tiendas/tiends.json")
 Call<Data> getTiendas();
```

do not forget to use the new object at onResponse:

```
List<Tiendas> listaObtenida = response.body().getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with Retrofit. For a JSON, a `field` is an object, `[]` is an array, `{}` is a POJO.

In your first JSON, you have a `data` object with type `List`(or `Array`). Therefore, you will need to create a POJO on top (Access Modifier is omitted for simplicity)

```
class DataClazz {
    List<Tiendas> data;
}
```